# Numerical library for Scala

Tags: java, scala, math, optimization, numerical-methods

I'm looking for a library to do numerical computing in Scala (or Java, although something that can use scala functions would be way nicer!) with at least the following capabilities:

- L-BFGS
- Minimizers (Powell, QuasiNewton, ...)
- Numerical differentiation of multivariable functions
- Numerical integration (not strictly necessary but highly preferred)

I'm also only looking for something that's actively maintained (last update during 2011 at the earliest), preferably but not necessarily free.
Also, numerical stability is required, aka all operations should be implemented in a way that gives consistent results where precision is preserved as much as possible.

I'm already aware of IMSL, but would prefer something else.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Commons math](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/overview-summary.html)?

Comment: Would work if it exposed a public API for numerical differentiation and had a Powell optimizer. Also, can't seem to find much information about numerical stability or performance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SuanShu](https://nm.dev) is a Java math library of numerical methods for numerical analysis.

Comment: seems just what I was looking for. thanks! bounty well deserved

Answer (score 2):

Late to this...

Try ND4S -- it supports n-dimensional arrays for Scala and other JVM-based languages.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ND4S
- https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4s

It's linked to an open-source framework called Deeplearning4j, which implements algorithms such as LBFGS.

- http://deeplearning4j.org

Answer (score 1):

There is [Scalala](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala/wiki) for Scala, but I am not sure it covers your need.

There are also the ones listed in this SO question: [Java Scientific Packages similar to SciPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482305/java-scientific-packages-similar-to-scipy).

Comment: Scalala is definitely good but it falls short on several of my needs... The link to the other question is good indeed, but not resolutive :(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ScalaLab](http://code.google.com/p/scalalab/) and its dependencies

Comment: From a quick look, seems to fall short at least on numerical differentiation and integration. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://code.google.com/p/scalalab/ and http://commons.apache.org/math/ I am not sure if they matches you needs but they are updated and have a lots of functions

Answer (score 0):

What about `breeze`, which is used in `scalanlp`? I see Spark is using it in the implementation of its LBFGS method too.